# If coaxial cables transfer energy through magnetic waves, why don't they simply use the current waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Coaxial waves transfer information from the magnetic waves propagating through the coaxial cable, caused by the voltage and current waves, right?

Why don't they simply transfer information directly through the current waves?

Answer (score 2):

> Coaxial [cables] transfer information [by] [electro]magnetic waves ... caused by the voltage and current waves, right?

You could equally say the currents in the conductors are caused by the electromagnetic waves in the dielectric.

Maxwell's equations tell us that you can't have one without the other.

> Why don't they simply transfer information directly through the current waves?

In fact, for engineering purposes, we often do analyze coaxial cable behavior in terms of current and voltage on the conductors, using the [telegrapher's equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegrapher's_equations).

However, this model is only an approximation of reality, because a coaxial cable (used at the frequencies where its transmission line behavior is significant) is not a lumped circuit, and therefore there isn't, strictly speaking, a well defined electrostatic potential function that describes it exactly.

Comment: I don't understand how your explanation explains why current isn't used. I know the telegrapher's equations model it in terms of current and voltage.

Comment: Also, how can I say currents in the conductors are caused by electromagnetic waves, since the generator generates current and not EM waves

Comment: Also, I think the electric waves aren't used right? They radiate outwards

Comment: There is no self-propagating "electric wave" or "magnetic wave", there are only electromagnetic waves which have both electric and magnetic field components. And they do radiate in free space, but can also be confined by a waveguide, of which a coaxial line is one type.

Comment: Similarly, you can't have current in a conductor without voltage or voltage differences without current. So whether you analyze the voltage signal or current signal in the telegrapher's equations is your choice.

Comment: but why doesn't the receiving end of a coaxial cable analyze current signals instead

Comment: The receiving end of a cable doesn't "analyze" anything. It just acts according to physical laws. And (like I said in my answer) we can indeed analyze that action in terms of current if we like.

Comment: We do, whenever it's the most convenient way to analyze it. What makes you think think we don't?